# Multiple BPEL/ Mediator payloads how to store in DB using DB adapter

Tags: soa, adapter, bpel, jca, mediator

I have huge XML which is XSD define for the same and have complex types which required around > 50 DB tables to store the entire XML.
Have one parent table which has reference ID to child tables.

Now first I want store the parent table and get the ID and use the same ID to store child tables (it has parent child relationship up to 5 or 6 levels)
How can I define / use the BPEL process.

I want to use the file adapter to read the XML file.
And I need to define BPEL process with mediators if required?
And use the DB adapter to store the data.

My questions are how can I define BPEL process with huge XSD which had multiple elements?
How can I use db adapter to store more than 50 tables and getting parent ID for child tables?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One method of solving this:
I think you need a composite solution of an ESB ([WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus)) and Dataservices ([WSO2 Dataservices](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/)).

You need to create data services to insert data into the Database tables. See [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS263/RDBMS+Sample) sample

Then you can use the ESB to read the large XML file. For this you can use the [VFS](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/VFS+Transport) transport that is shipped with WSO2 ESB. See [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Sample+12+Using+the+File+System+as+Transport+Medium+%28VFS%29) sample.

After that you can configure ESB to use the created dataservices to insert the data read from ESB.

I do not think BPEL is a right choice here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.  One would be to so several database inserts.  The other would be to pass the data to a pl/sql function and have it do the actual insert.